# how to bind countries and All countries in dropdown in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, combobox

Data is bind sucessfully in this case but when i click on All Merchant Names its bind data into gridview

```
Sub MerchantDropDown()
      Dim ds As New DataSet
      ds = Utilities.spMerchantName1()
      ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataSource = ds
      ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataTextField = "MerchantName1"
      ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataValueField = "MerchantID"
      ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataBind()
      ddlMerchantDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, "All Merchant Names")
End Sub
Sub BindDataGrid()
      Try
        dsTran = Utilities.GetPointsBalanceDS(-999, IIf(txtEmbossLine.Text.Trim.Length = 0, "-999", txtEmbossLine.Text.Trim), IIf(txtEmbossName.Text.Trim.Length = 0, "-999", txtEmbossName.Text.Trim), IIf(ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text.Trim.Length = 0, "-999", ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text.Trim))

            sRecCount = dsTran.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            grdTransactions.DataSource = dsTran
            grdTransactions.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: For example i have merchant names like Sajjad,hasan,abbas and All Merchant name when i click on sajjad, or hasan or abbas data bind into grid but when i click on All Merchant name bind showing null i want when i click on All merchant name its show me all merchant names

Comment: where you binding grid? can you show that code?